# How to melt DataFrame when I don't have any column to preserve in id_vars

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert this df:

[image: 1]

Into something like this:

```
index   Date          Rate
1       21-02-2021    8.712
2       21-03-2021    8.712
3       21-05-2021    8.712
```

I am trying to use function melt(), but it requires id_vars and I don't really know what to put there to get correct output.
This is what I got:

```
exr_tall = exr.melt(id_vars='index', var_name = 'Date', value_name = 'Rate')
```

Anyone could help me please?

Comment: `df=df.T.rename(columns={18:'Date', 19: 'Rate'})`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you, it worked, but how can I replace the most left column with index column?

Comment: Chain that with `.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY this pivot:

```
df.pivot(index = 'index', columns = 'Date', values = 'Rate')
```